# What is the format of the 'orient' agument to pandas.DataFrame.to_json()?

Tags: python, pandas

Looking at [the pandas Documentation on DataFrame's to_json method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html), the `orient` argument is ambiguously explained. The type of the argument it accepts is a string, not a dict. However it seems like there are actually three things it can accept and each has their own default: Series (default 'index'), DataFrame (default 'columns'), and "The format of the JSON string" (no default).

I'd like to know what the acceptable values for the `orient` argument are and what each of them do to the output json.

Answer (score 14):

The format of the JSON string is just how the output will look like for every parameter as following

- split : dict like {index -> [index], columns -> [columns], data -> [values]}
- records : list like [{column -> value}, ... , {column -> value}]
- index : dict like {index -> {column -> value}}
- columns : dict like {column -> {index -> value}}
- values : just the values array

Comment: Breaking that out is indeed useful--it seems to be the meaningful part of the docs and playing around with those arguments, it makes sense.
What does the following part refer to? Is this page also documenting Series.to_json() in addition to DataFrame.to_json() ?

    * Series
      - default is ‘index’
      - allowed values are: {‘split’,’records’,’index’}
    * DataFrame
      - default is ‘columns’
      - allowed values are: {‘split’,’records’,’index’,’columns’,’values’}

Comment: @AndrewM.Farrell yes, it is.